# Mitigate DDoS Proxy attack

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, ddos

In last days my apache is being attacked by many connections from proxies. I've identified the source but could not block the attack effectively.

The attacker seems to be using pyloris or a variation of this to attack my apache on port 80.

I installed nginx and varnish but not enough to support the extra load.

I also added a rule in iptables to drop packets that contain the string "X-Forwarded-For" but does not block all the proxies.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually pyloris attacks are utilised using TOR network. As first step I would suggest you to block ip addresses of TOR network and check if it helps at all.

[Here is a list of TOR network's ip addresses](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/)

Let us know if it helps

Comment: Additionally, setting low timeouts in nginx and connlimits via iptables can help.

Comment: @tristan I set the nginx timeout to 3s and connlimit to 30/s but the problem is that the requests come from many different ips and all are proxies.

Comment: @Hex It does not help much because most proxies are not those who are on this list.

Comment: @Digorp what are some of the example 'proxies' that you're seeing?  What scale of connections are you receiving?

Comment: @Digorp : Can you try the iptables rule I added to my answer?

Comment: @Hex
Your rule above helped a lot. Now the server load is: load average: 6.07, 7.86, 12.04

Comment: @tristan
Without Hex's rule:
netstat -an |grep ":80" | wc -l
11363

With:
netstat -an | grep ":80" | wc -l
2727

Comment: Without the above rule, the load goes up to 100+ and the server hangs. But anyway load 6.07 is a bit high. Guys, do you have more suggestions?

Comment: Ok, there are some proxies that do not forward requests using exact "X-Forwarded-For" phrase. Use ngrep to check how other proxies are sending requests.

Comment: I have edited my answer, have a look at it.

Comment: @Digorp I was more getting at "what are the IPs of the remote hosts?"

Comment: @tristan here are some ips dropped by the Hex's rule [link](http://pastebin.com/m7p7DZsY)

Comment: Another thing, as you should already know the ip address in x-forwarded-for flag is the ip of attacker. I would suggest you to report that ip to authorities.